# Is there an optimal way to create logical columns from physical column using SQL query statement?

Tags: sql-server, subquery

I'm writing a SQL query using a table. My requirement is that I need to generate two logical columns from one physical column with certain conditions. In SQL how to generate two logical columns in final result set?

I have so far tried using sub-queries to derive those logical columns. But that sub-query returns error when incorporate it as a column in main query.

Overall there are other tables which will be joined using `SQL JOIN` to derive respective columns.

Columns:

1. `CarrierName NVARCHAR(10)`
2. `MonthDate DATETIME`
3. `Stage INT`

**Scenario:**
In my SQL Server table there is a column called `Stage` of type `int` that contains values like 1, 2, 3, 4.

Now, I have two date criteria to apply on above column to derive two logical columns in final result set.

**Criteria #1:**

Get carriers from past 12 months and priors to past month end date and value of "CurrentStage" should be less than  and derive "PriorStage"

**Example:**

**Current month is: March 2019 (2019-03-25) or any given date**
Past latest month end date would be: 2019-02-28

**12 months prior to above past latest month would be:**
From 2018-02-01 To 2019-01-31

**Criteria #2:**

Get Carriers from past latest month end date and derive "CurrentStage"

While writing two independent SQL SELECT statements I get my desired results.
My challenge is when I think them to integrate in one select statement.

I get this error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression

Code:

```
DECLARE @DATE DATETIME
SET @DATE = '2018-08-25';

--QUERY 1 - RECORDS WITH PREVIOUS MONTH END DATE
SELECT 
    T1.CarrierName AS 'Carrier_Number', 
    T1.Stage AS 'Monitoring_Stage–Current'
FROM 
    table1 T1
WHERE 
    T1.Stage IS NOT NULL AND 
    CONVERT(DATE, T1.MonthDate) = CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(D, -(DAY(@DATE)), @DATE)) 

--QUERY 2 - RECORDS FROM PAST 12 MONTHS PRIOR PREVIOUS MONTH END DATE
SELECT 
    T2.CarrierName,
    T2.Stage AS 'Monitoring_Stage–Prior'
FROM
    table2 T2
WHERE 
    T2.Stage IS NOT NULL AND 
    CONVERT(DATE, T2.MonthDate) BETWEEN CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(M, -12, DATEADD(D, -(DAY(@DATE)), @DATE)))                         
                                    AND CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(D, -(DAY(@DATE) + (DAY(DATEADD(D, -(DAY(@DATE)), @DATE)))), @DATE)) 
    AND T2.Stage) > (SELECT DISTINCT MAX(m.Stage AS INT))
                     FROM table1 m                                
                     WHERE CONVERT(DATE, m.MonthDate) = CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(D, -(DAY(@DATE)), @DATE)) 
                       AND T2.CarrierName = m.CarrierName)
```

My final expected result set should contain below columns.
Where `CurrentStage` value is less than `PriorStage` value.

**Expected Results**

```
CarrierName   | CurrentStage | PriorStage
--------------+--------------+-------------
C11122        | 1            | 2
C32233        | 3            | 4
```

**Actual Result**

I am looking for alternatives. I.e. CTE, Union, temp table etc.

Something like:

```
SELECT 
    CarrierName,
    Query 1 Result As 'CurrentStage',
    Query 2 Result As 'PrioreStage'
FROM
    table1
```

To improve this post, I am adding my response here. My resolution below for this posted question is still under evaluation hence not posting it as my final answer. But it really brought a light to my effort.

**RESOLUTION:**

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT M.CarrierName, A.[CurrentStage], B.[PriorStage] 
    FROM
    --QUERY 1 - RECORDS WITH CURRENT MONTH END DATE
(SELECT M.CarrierName, M.CarrierID
    , Stage AS 'CurrentStage'
    FROM table1 M 
    WHERE M.Stage IS NOT NULL AND 
    CONVERT(date, M.MonthDate) = CONVERT(date, DATEADD(D,-(DAY(@DATE)), @DATE)) 
) 
A **inner join**
(
--QUERY 2 - RECORDS FROM PAST 12 MONTHS PRIOR CURRENT MONTH END DATE
SELECT M2.CarrierName, M2.CarrierID
    , Stage AS 'PriorStage'
    FROM table1 M2
    WHERE M2.Stage IS NOT NULL AND 
    CONVERT(date, M2.MonthDate) BETWEEN CONVERT(date, DATEADD(M, -12, DATEADD(D,-(DAY(@DATE)), @DATE))) 
                                            AND CONVERT(date, DATEADD(D,-(DAY(@DATE)+(DAY(DATEADD(D,-(DAY(@DATE)), @DATE)))), @DATE)) 
    AND M2.Stage > (SELECT DISTINCT max(m.Stage)
                                                  FROM table1 m
                                                  WHERE CONVERT(date, m.MonthDate) = CONVERT(date, DATEADD(D,-(DAY(@DATE)), @DATE)) AND
                                                  M2.CarrierName = m.CarrierName
                                                 )

) B on b.Carrier_Number = a.Carrier_Number
INNER JOIN table1 M ON A.CarrierID = M.CarrierID AND B.CarrierID = M.CarrierID
```

Comment: Not enough information to help you.  You show us the code of the separate statements that work.  You say you get an error when you try to integrate them in a single select, but you don't show us the code that generates the error.  There is no way we can see what you are doing wrong to get the error, or suggest how it can be fixed.

Comment: I understand @TabAlleman. But the query which was throwing error was somehow not in a shape I could post. Sometimes when problem is not so generic it is little annoying and weird to decipher or reproduce. But hatsoff to StackOverflow that soon after posting this issue, I was provided with not exact solution but a way which at least took me little closer to the result set how I wanted it. I updated my question with resolution. Just not posted it as I am still evaluating with various data that I have. Thanks for showing up though! I appreciate it.